# Acessar valores de uma Matriz de objetos

Tags: java, matriz

Tenho um trabalho onde devo criar um estacionamento, no básico do Java mesmo.

Então tenho minha classe `Carros`:

```java
package estacionebemestacionamento;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.text.*;

public class Carros {
   private String Placa;
   private String Modelo;
   private String DataEntrada;
   private String HoraEntrada;
   private int HoraEntradaHora;
   private int HoraEntradaMinutos;
   private int DataEntradaDia;
   private int DataEntradaMes;
   private int DataEntradaAno;
   private String DataSaida;
   private String HoraSaida;


    public String getPlaca() { //Retorna a placa do veiculo
        return this.Placa;
    }

    public void setPlaca(String Placa) { //Armazena a Placa do Veiculo
        this.Placa = Placa;
    }

    public String getModelo() { //Retorna o Modelo
        return this.Modelo;
    }

    public void setModelo(String Modelo) { //Armazena o Modelo
        this.Modelo = Modelo;
    }

    public String getDataEntrada() { //Retorna a Data de Entrada do Veiculo
        return this.DataEntrada;
    }

    public void setDataEntrada(String DataEntrada) { //Armazena a Data de Entrada Do Veiculo
        this.DataEntrada = DataEntrada;
    }

    public String getHoraEntrada() { //Retorna a Hora de Entrada
        return this.HoraEntrada;
    }

    public void setHoraEntrada(String HoraEntrada) { //Armazena a Hora de Entrada
        this.HoraEntrada = HoraEntrada;
    }

    public String getDataSaida() {
        return this.DataSaida;
    }

    public void setDataSaida(String DataSaida) {
        this.DataSaida = DataSaida;
    }

    public String getHoraSaida() {
        return this.HoraSaida;
    }

    public void setHoraSaida(String HoraSaida) {
        this.HoraSaida = HoraSaida;
    }

    /**
     * @return the HoraEntradaHora
     */
    public int getHoraEntradaHora() {
        return HoraEntradaHora;
    }

    /**
     * @param HoraEntradaHora the HoraEntradaHora to set
     */
    public void setHoraEntradaHora(int HoraEntradaHora) {
        this.HoraEntradaHora = HoraEntradaHora;
    }

    /**
     * @return the HoraEntradaMinutos
     */
    public int getHoraEntradaMinutos() {
        return HoraEntradaMinutos;
    }

    /**
     * @param HoraEntradaMinutos the HoraEntradaMinutos to set
     */
    public void setHoraEntradaMinutos(int HoraEntradaMinutos) {
        this.HoraEntradaMinutos = HoraEntradaMinutos;
    }

    /**
     * @return the DataEntradaDia
     */
    public int getDataEntradaDia() {
        return DataEntradaDia;
    }

    /**
     * @param DataEntradaDia the DataEntradaDia to set
     */
    public void setDataEntradaDia(int DataEntradaDia) {
        this.DataEntradaDia = DataEntradaDia;
    }

    /**
     * @return the DataEntradaMes
     */
    public int getDataEntradaMes() {
        return DataEntradaMes;
    }

    /**
     * @param DataEntradaMes the DataEntradaMes to set
     */
    public void setDataEntradaMes(int DataEntradaMes) {
        this.DataEntradaMes = DataEntradaMes;
    }

    /**
     * @return the DataEntradaAno
     */
    public int getDataEntradaAno() {
        return DataEntradaAno;
    }

    /**
     * @param DataEntradaAno the DataEntradaAno to set
     */
    public void setDataEntradaAno(int DataEntradaAno) {
        this.DataEntradaAno = DataEntradaAno;
    }
}
```

Da minha classe `carros` eu crio uma `Matriz[3][3]` do tipo `Carros`, até ai tudo bem.

Na hora de chamar minha função para inserir um carro eu faço assim:

```java
public void Entrada(String Placa, String Modelo, String DataEntrada, String HoraEntrada, int HoraEntradaHora, int HoraEntradaMinutos, int DataEntradaDia, int DataEntradaMes, int DataEntradaAno){                                 
      this.Placa = Placa;
      this.Modelo = Modelo;
      this.DataEntrada = DataEntrada;
      this.HoraEntrada = HoraEntrada; 
      this.DataEntradaDia = DataEntradaDia;
      this.DataEntradaMes = DataEntradaMes;
      this.DataEntradaAno = DataEntradaAno;
      this.HoraEntradaHora = HoraEntradaHora;
      this.HoraEntradaMinutos = HoraEntradaMinutos;

      gv.setPlaca(Placa);
      gv.setModelo(Modelo);    
      gv.setDataEntrada(DataEntrada); // Armazena a data na função
      gv.setHoraEntrada(HoraEntrada);      
      gv.setDataEntradaDia(DataEntradaDia);
      gv.setDataEntradaMes(DataEntradaMes);
      gv.setDataEntradaAno(DataEntradaAno);
      gv.setHoraEntradaHora(HoraEntradaHora);
      gv.setHoraEntradaMinutos(HoraEntradaMinutos);
}
```

E depois eu aloco o que esta na variável `gv` em uma posição informada pelo usuário na minha matriz `garagem[rua][fileira]` dessa forma:

```java
public void AlocaCarro(int Rua, int Fileira) throws Exception{
     if (garagem[Rua][Fileira] != null) {
         throw new Exception("VAGA JA OCUPADA / VAGA NÃO EXISTE.");
     }else{     
         garagem[Rua][Fileira] = gv;                    
     }                 
}
```

Até ai ao meu ver esta funcionando, o problema esta quando eu cadastro mais de 1 carro em diferentes posições dessa matriz, e faço uma pesquisa por placa para me retornar a posição da placa, ele sempre me retorna como se todas as posições da matriz estivesse com a mesma placa cadastrada, parece que ele pega sempre o ultimo resultado informado.

Se eu fosse fazer uma impressão de todos os veículos em seus lugares, ele retorna também tudo igual.

```java
public void ProcurarCarroAlocado(){          
    for (int l = 0; l < garagem.length;l++){
      for (int c = 0; c < garagem[l].length;c++){ 
          if(garagem[l][c]!=null){
            gv = garagem[l][c];
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Veículo com a Placa: "+gv.getPlaca()+ "localizado na Rua: "+l+"Fileira: "+c);            
          }
      }   
    }
} 

public class EstacioneBemEstacionamento{   
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

      String Placa = "", Modelo = "";      
      String DataEntrada = null, DataSaida = null, HoraEntrada = null; 
      int HoraEntradaMinutos, HoraEntradaHora, HoraSaida, DataEntradaDia, DataEntradaMes, DataEntradaAno;   
      GaragemVagas criarVagas = new GaragemVagas();
      criarVagas.CriaVagas(); //CRIO AS VAGAS DO ESTACIONAMENTO.
      Utilitarios u = new Utilitarios();
      int Rua = 0;
      int Fileira = 0;

      //CRIA MENUS.
       System.out.println("\n\n\n");
       int opcao = 0, continuar = 1;              
        do{                        
            opcao = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "0 - SAIR \n1 - ENTRADA DE VEICULOS \n2 - PROCURAR CARRO POR PLACA \n3 - RELATORIO DIARIO \nInforme a Opção: "));                        
            switch(opcao){
              case 0:
                opcao =0;
              break;

              case 1:
                u.cls();
                Placa = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "INFORME A PLACA: ");
                Modelo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Placa: "+Placa, "INFORME O MODELO: ");

                do {
                  DataEntradaDia = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Placa: "+Placa+"\nModelo: "+Modelo, "\nINFORME O DIA: "));
                }while ((DataEntradaDia < 1) || (DataEntradaDia > 31));
                do {
                  DataEntradaMes = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Placa: "+Placa+"\nModelo: "+Modelo+"\nDia: "+DataEntradaDia+"/", "\nINFORME O MÊS: "));                
                }while((DataEntradaMes < 1) || (DataEntradaMes > 12));
                 DataEntradaAno = 2015;


                DataEntrada = Integer.toString(DataEntradaDia) + "/" + Integer.toString(DataEntradaMes) +"/"+ Integer.toString(DataEntradaAno);

                do {
                  HoraEntradaHora = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Placa: "+Placa+"\nModelo: "+Modelo+"\nData de Entrada: "+DataEntrada, "\nInforme a Hora das 8 até as 18 -> (ignorando .:,)"));
                } while ((HoraEntradaHora < 8) || (HoraEntradaHora > 18));

                do {
                  HoraEntradaMinutos = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Placa: "+Placa+"\nModelo: "+Modelo+"\nData de Entrada: "+DataEntrada, "\nInforme os Minutos das 0 até as 59 -> (ignorando .:,)"));
                }while ((HoraEntradaMinutos < 0) || (HoraEntradaMinutos > 59));

                HoraEntrada = Integer.toString(HoraEntradaHora) + ":" + Integer.toString(HoraEntradaMinutos);                
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Placa: "+Placa+"\nModelo: "+Modelo+"\nData de Entrada: "+DataEntrada+"\nHora de Entrada: "+HoraEntrada);

                int op2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Deseja verificar as vagas Disponíveis? \n (1)-SIM (2)-NÃO"));                
                if (op2 == 1){//IMPRIME AS VAGAS NA TELA PARA A SELEÇÃO DO USUARIO.
                  criarVagas.ImprimeVagas();
                }//FIM IMPRESSÃO

              do {                
                Rua = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Informe a Rua onde deseja estacionar:"));
                Fileira = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Informe a Fileira Correspondente: "));                                     
                  try {                          
                    criarVagas.Entrada(Placa, Modelo, DataEntrada, HoraEntrada, DataEntradaDia, DataEntradaMes, DataEntradaAno, HoraEntradaHora, HoraEntradaMinutos);                      
                    criarVagas.AlocaCarro(Rua, Fileira);
                    continuar = 0;
                  }catch (Exception ex){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Vaga Ja Ocupada por favor tente outra.");
                    continuar = 1;
                  }
                }while (continuar != 0);
                u.cls();//limpa saida de dados.
                break;

            case 2: //MostraPosição do Carro.
              String PlacaPesquisa = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Informe a Placa de Pesquisa: ");
              criarVagas.ProcurarCarroAlocado(PlacaPesquisa);

              break;
            case 3:
                criarVagas.ImprimeVagas();
                break;

            case 4:
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Opção inválida.");
            }
        } while(opcao != 0);
    }// fim main
}//fim sistema
```

Como ficaria minha classe `GaragemVagas`?

```java
package estacionebemestacionamento;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GaragemVagas {
  int x,y,z;
  Carros garagem[][] = new Carros[3][3];  

  String Modelo;
  String Placa;
  String DataEntrada;
  String HoraEntrada;
  String DataSaida;
  String HoraSaida;
  int DataEntradaDia, DataEntradaMes, DataEntradaAno, HoraEntradaHora, HoraEntradaMinutos;
  int tamL;
  int tamC;
  Carros gv = new Carros();

  public void CriaVagas(){    
  //CRIA MATRIZ MULTIDIMENSIONAL DO ESTACIONAMENTO COM NENHUMA VAGA PREENCHIDA.
    for (int l = 0;l < garagem.length ;l ++){
      for (int c = 0; c < garagem[l].length; c++){
        garagem[l][c] = null;
      }
    }
  }
  public void ImprimeVagas(){
    String output = "Ruas\tFileiras\tStatus";
    String status = "";

    System.out.printf("VERIFICANDO VAGAS DISPONÍVEIS. \n");
      for(int i = 0; i < garagem.length; i++)   {    
        for(int j = 0; j < garagem[i].length; j++)    {  
           if (garagem[i][j] != null) {
             status = "Ocupada";
             output += "\n " +i+ "\t" + "" +j+ "\t("+status+")\t";
             //System.out.printf("Rua %d - Fileira %d  ( %s )\t",i,j,status);                
           }else if (garagem[i][j] == null) {
             status = "Disponível";
             output += "\n " +i+ "\t" + "" +j+ "\t("+status+")\t";
             //System.out.printf("Rua %d - Fileira %d  ( %s )\t",i,j,status);                
           }

        } 
          output += "";
         //System.out.println("");    
      }
      JTextArea outputArea = new JTextArea();
      outputArea.setText(output);
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,outputArea, "Status das Vagas",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
  } 

public void AlocaCarro(int Rua, int Fileira) throws Exception{    
  Carros novo = gv;    
  if (garagem[Rua][Fileira] != null) {
         throw new Exception("VAGA JA OCUPADA / VAGA NÃO EXISTE.");
  }else{        
      garagem[Rua][Fileira] = novo;  //guardar a referência para esta nova instância                  
  }                 
}

public void Entrada(String Placa, String Modelo, String DataEntrada, String HoraEntrada, int DataEntradaDia, int DataEntradaMes, int DataEntradaAno, int HoraEntradaHora, int HoraEntradaMinutos){                                             
      gv.setPlaca(Placa);
      gv.setModelo(Modelo);    
      gv.setDataEntrada(DataEntrada); 
      gv.setHoraEntrada(HoraEntrada);      
      gv.setDataEntradaDia(DataEntradaDia);
      gv.setDataEntradaMes(DataEntradaMes);
      gv.setDataEntradaAno(DataEntradaAno);
      gv.setHoraEntradaHora(HoraEntradaHora);
      gv.setHoraEntradaMinutos(HoraEntradaMinutos);
    }

public void ProcurarCarroAlocado(String placa){          
    String output = "Placa\tRua\tFileira";

   for (int l = 0; l < garagem.length;l++){
       for (int c = 0; c < garagem[l].length;c++){ 
           if(garagem[l][c]!=null){
              if ( garagem[l][c].getPlaca().equals(placa)){
                 output += "\n "+garagem[l][c].getPlaca()+ "\t"+l+"\t"+c;  
              }         
           }
       }
       output +="";
   }
   JTextArea outputArea = new JTextArea();
   outputArea.setText(output);
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, outputArea, "Carro Localizado",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
} 

}
```

**Atualização**: Bruno, não estou conseguindo instanciar do jeito que me disse.

Comment: Removi temporariamente a minha resposta por agora fiquei na dúvida. Penso não ter entendido correctamente a questão. Podes colocar mais um pouco do teu código? A parte onde declaras a variável de instância 'gv' e onde estas a fazer a chamada ás funções Entrada() e AlocaCarro?

Comment: Na classe Carros tens que declarar o construtor de copia. Depois no método AlocaCarro() deves criar uma cópia do objecto gv da seguinte forma: "Carros novoCarro(gv);" e não "Carros novo = gv";

Comment: e como eu instancio o Carros gv = new Carros(); ? ele pede um parametro para o Carros(); qual coloco?

Comment: Criaste o método "public Carros(Carros o)" na tua classe Carros?

Comment: Sim criei public Carros(Carro outro) na classe Carros, do jeito que me disse, agora na classe GaragemVaga como eu instancio o Carros gv = new Carros(); ?

Comment: Cria também um outro construtor com a seguinte assinatura: "public Carros() {}.

Comment: Preciso dentro dele colocar os atributos também ou não?

Comment: No teu caso não, senão vais ter que alterar a forma como estas a instanciar o objecto. Para poderes executar "Carros gv = new Carros()" define o constructor sem parâmetros. Apenas "public Carros() {  }.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema então está na função `AlocaCarro(...)`. Tu deverias fazer uma cópia do objecto e guardar na tua matriz. Actualmente estás a criar um único objecto, que vais alterando durante a execução do teu programa e para o qual todas as posições da tua matriz apontam (mesmo endereço de memória).

Uma solução passa por criar um construtor de cópia que te permite obter o que desejas. - Tens outras formas para copiar objectos em Java, mas para este exemplo e visto tratar-se de uma introdução ao Java, recomendaria esta opção.

Na tua classe Carros defines o constructor da seguinte forma.

```
public Carros(Carros outro) {

  this.Placa = outro.placa;
  this.Modelo = outro.Modelo;
  this.DataEntrada = outro.DataEntrada
  (...fazer o mesmo para os restantes atributos...)
}
```

Depois no teu método AlocaCarro fazes

```
public void AlocaCarro(int Rua, int Fileira) throws Exception{
  if (garagem[Rua][Fileira] != null) {
         throw new Exception("VAGA JA OCUPADA / VAGA NÃO EXISTE.");
  }else{     
      Carros novo(gv);  //Aqui crias uma nova instância do objecto
      garagem[Rua][Fileira] = novo;  //guardar a referência para esta nova instância                  
  }                 
}
```

A linha `Carros novo(gv);` cria um novo objecto que é uma cópia da instância `gv`.

Para procurar o carro por placa, podes fazer:

```
public void ProcurarCarroAlocado(String placa){          
   for (int l = 0; l < garagem.length;l++){
       for (int c = 0; c < garagem[l].length;c++){ 
           if(garagem[l][c]!=null){
              if ( garagem[l][c].GetPlaca().equals(placa)
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Veículo com a Placa: "+ placa+ "localizado na Rua: "+l+"Fileira: "+c);  
              }         
           }
       }   
   }
}
```